# How to count the occurrence of a str in values of a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm pretty new to Python but I'm helping on a project to scope out the number of biased words in the data.

I currently have a list of coded words:

`male_coded_words = ['active','adventurous','aggress','ambitio','analy','assert']`

I have a dictionary of job titles and skills:

`jobsdict = {'fork lift truck driver': ['fork lift truck driv','assert], 'assistant fraud and payment risk manager': ['fraud', 'online fraud', 'fraud detect', 'payment system', 'risk manag'], 'paralegal vacancy corporate immigration (london office)': ['legal', 'microsoft offic', 'communication skil'], 'transport operator': ['transport','active'], 'year 5 primary teacher': ['newham'], 'multi agency safeguarding administrator': ['admin', 'social work', 'safeguard', 'social work admin', 'children administr', 'social work administr', 'safeguarding administr']`

I'd like to iterate through the dictionary and find, for each key, how many times an item in the list of male_coded_words appears.

An output in the form of a dictionary in the form of
`{'fork lift truck driver': "count":"1", "coded_words":["assert"].....}`

My code so far;

```
final_count = 0
final_output = {}

for k, v in jobsdict:
    final_output[k] = []
    if 'analy' in str(v):
        n = final_count + 1
    else:
        n = 0  
    final_output[k].append(n)
    final_output[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea here is to take advantage of Python's [set](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html) objects, which act as unordered alternatives to lists. Operations on sets tend to be a lot faster than equivalent ones on lists. I also use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for brevity and a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object to automatically count the number of instances of coded words.The following script should give you the output you specified:

```
from collections import Counter

# General form of the data provided above, for reference
# male_coded_words = ['active', ...]
# jobsdict = {'fork lift truck driver': ['fork lift truck driv','assert'], ...}

result = {k: Counter(set(v) & set(male_coded_words)) for k,v in jobsdict.items()}

# result will look like {'fork lift truck driver': {"assert": 1}, ...}.
# If no coded words exist for a specific job, then its value in the 
# result dict will just be an empty set.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner but I would look into Regular Expressions and make a count of it (the most simple way I can think of)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way other than to use less than 2 for loops, one to iterate over the `jobsdict`, and another the coded words. Also, use `jobsdict.items()` to iterate over it by both keys and values :

```py
final_count = 0
final_output = {}

for k, v in jobsdict.items():
    count, words = 0, []
    s = ''.join(v) 
    # merge all the strings into one to avoid a third nested loop iterating over them
    for w in male_coded_words:
        c = s.count(w) 
        # can be replaced with `w in s` if you don't want to count multiple occurrences of a word each time
        if c:
            count += c
            words.append(w)
    final_count += count
    final_output[k] = [count, words]

print(final_output, final_count)
```

This gave me this output :

```
{'fork lift truck driver': [1, ['assert']], 'assistant fraud and payment risk manager': [0, []], 'paralegal vacancy corporate immigration (london office)': [0, []], 'transport operator': [1, ['active']], 'year 5 primary teacher': [0, []], 'multi agency safeguarding administrator': [0, []]} 2
```

Edit: if you want the `final_output` to contain dictionaries within it, replace the 2nd last line with `final_output[k] = {"count":count, "words":words}`